# Is example-image-a compatible with DVI mode?

Tags: graphics, dvi-mode, mwe

I could not get the expected result when compiling the following with `latex-dvips-ps2pdf`. The unexpected result is just a single blank page with a page number 1. :-)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics{example-image-a}

\end{document}
```

Is `example-image-a` compatible with `latex` (i.e. DVI mode)? Is there an EPS version for that image?

Loading `mwe` package did not help as well.

### Log from `latex.exe`

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (MiKTeX 2.9)
entering extended mode
(F:\test.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ar
abic, armenian, assamese, basque, bengali, bokmal, bulgarian, catalan, coptic, 
croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, ga
lician, german, german-x-2009-06-19, greek, gujarati, hindi, hungarian, iceland
ic, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kannada, kurmanji, lao, latin, lat
vian, lithuanian, malayalam, marathi, mongolian, mongolianlmc, monogreek, ngerm
an, ngerman-x-2009-06-19, nynorsk, oriya, panjabi, pinyin, polish, portuguese, 
romanian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, swis
sgerman, tamil, telugu, turkish, turkmen, ukenglish, ukrainian, uppersorbian, u
senglishmax, welsh, loaded.
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\mwe\mwe.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\graphics.cfg")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\dvips.def")))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\lipsum\lipsum.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\blindtext\blindtext.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tools\xspace.sty"))) (F:\test.aux
) <example-image-a.eps> [1] (F:\test.aux) )
Output written on test.dvi (1 page, 284 bytes).
Transcript written on test.log.
```

Comment: Do you have the `mwe` package installed?

Comment: What is the unexpected result you are getting?

Comment: Well, why do you not write that in the first place!

Comment: @Forgiver: It's not clear what exactly happens, e.g. if you get an error or not etc. and this is important to figure out what exactly goes wrong. Sentences like "it doesn't work" or "not the expected result" are not helpful. Your log file clearly shows that the EPS file is found and used. The manual clearly states that EPS versions are provided. It works fine for me in DVI and PDF mode. What file are you viewing? The DVI, EPS or PDF file? Note that some DVI viewer might not show included EPS files.

Comment: Locate the `example-image-a.eps` file (e.g. `kpsewhich example-image-a.eps` or use the search tool of your OS) and check if it is OK.

Comment: Please check if the file is OK, i.e. if it shows the correct content and not just an empty content etc.

Comment: Sorry, is `latex-dvips-ps2pdf` one tool or do you mean you are using `latex`, then `dvips` and then `ps2pdf`? I don't know MiKTeX very well and searching for it doesn't give much results.

Comment: I removed my comments as they are no longer important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an `example-image-a.eps` provided by [`mwe`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mwe) as well as EPS versions for the other images, as stated in the manual.

However, there seems to be an issue with these EPS files as Ulrike pointed out. They seem not include the proper headers which make a PS file an EPS file. I, as author of `mwe`, will rebuild the EPS files and upload them as soon I find time.
I tested the existing versions with TeX Live 2011 under Ubuntu Linux where they worked fine, but other tools might be more picky about the EPS headers.

Comment: I can confirm that the `eps` doesn't work. The correct place is reserved but the image doesn't show up after latex + dvips in gsview. An inspection of the some of the eps-files shows that they are no real eps (they start with `%!PS-Adobe-2.0`). Everything works fine if I convert them with the `epswrite` device to eps. Then they start with `%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0` and show up correctly. I would say you forgot the -E switch when calling dvips.

Comment: Thanks @Ulrike, this helps a lot. I tested the EPS only with TeX Live were they worked and trusted that they are fine. Indeed they might be "normal" PS files. I will change my build work-flow and upload a corrected version.

Comment: @Forgiver: I updated the answer. Please note that package bugs are actually not on-topic IMHO, but should be reported directly to the package author. Until Ulrike's comment I thought it's rather an installation or similar issue on your side.